# How organize and ensure that all script and css are loaded without putting them on each page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to web development and building a C# web MVC application in Visual Studios. I am using Jquery,AngularJS,Twitter Bootsrap CSS and a bunch of other 3rd party JavaScripts.
I have included reference to all these files on every page which looks very nasty. I am using a master layout page for all the other pages so I thought that referencing everything that is required would resolve my problem but that didnt work out.

How can I store all the required scripts and css in one place and have all web pages get everything from there?

Comment: You can reference all the scripts in your master page/layout. If that isn't working, you're doing something wrong. Also, if you're using MVC4, create a new project based on the basic template, and look at how they use bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a layout that is used very every page, and make sure that layout is calling a header. Then throw your script files in there.

Although I would suggest against loading ALL your javascript files for ALL of the pages, you might take a performance hit once you scale upward. You can put checks in your header to filter the ones you need.